# A Poisson problem

Tags: probability

How would you approach this:

Master's degrees of faculty F of university U form a Poisson process. Especially the number of graduates in the year $(2000 + i)$ where $i \in \mathbb{N}$ is random variable $$X_i \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda),$$ and aforementioned random variables are independent.

Faculty F's funding $Y_i$ for the year $(2000 + i)$ with $i \ge 3$ is proportional to the funding of three previous years, so $$Y_i = k(X_{i-3} + X_{i-2} + X_{i-1}),$$ where $k > 0$.

What is the probability, that $Y_i$ differs at most one-hundredth of its expected value?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
E\left[\frac{Y_i}k\right] &= E\left[(X_{i-3} + X_{i-2} + X_{i-1})\right]\\
&= E\left[X_{i-3}\right] + E\left[X_{i-2}\right] + E\left[X_{i-1}\right]\\
&=3\lambda
\end{align}
Since
$$\frac{Y_i}k=X_{i-3} + X_{i-2} + X_{i-1}$$
i.e. $\frac{Y_i}k$ is a sum of independent poisson varibles,
$$\frac{Y_i}k\sim\mathrm{Po}(3\lambda)$$

The probability you are finding is
$$P\left(|Y_i-3k\lambda|\le0.03k\lambda\right)=P\left(2.97k\lambda\le Y_i\le3.03k\lambda\right)=P\left(2.97\lambda\le \frac{Y_i}{k}\le3.03\lambda\right)$$

To evaluate this, you either utilize Central Limit Theorem provided the conditions are satisfied, or 
$$
P\left(2.97\lambda\le \frac{Y_i}{k}\le3.03\lambda\right)
=e^{-3\lambda}\sum_{i=\lceil2.97\lambda\rceil}^{\lfloor3.03\lambda\rfloor}\frac{(3\lambda)^i}{i!}$$
which is, while more accurate, much harder to compute with unknown $\lambda$.

Comment: This really helped me to understand this case. But, how can I solve the probability?

Comment: @HaydenSpetting Do you have access to a graphing calculator or a math software?

Comment: Yes, I have a CAS calculator, but it can't calculate that equation. I guess it must be solved by applying Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat  Your last edit deleted the question.  Please be careful.